# Read CSV from another folder in Jupiter Notebook (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import, jupyter-notebook

I have my CSV files in a Data Folder in Jupyter Notebook, then I have a few other notebooks that I want to rely on the CSV files in the Data Folder. How do I read in the CSV files From the Data Folder into the notebooks that I want the analysis to occur in? I'm using a Mac and doing this in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path to the csv file you want to put in pd.read_csv. For example, if your jupyter notebook is located on your Desktop, and the csv file (lets call it "my_project_1") is somewhere else, say in a folder called Projects, and that folder is in your Documents folder, then you specify the path as following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/your_user_name/Documents/Projects/my_project_1.csv')
```

Don't forget to change `your_user_name` to your actual user name.

Comment: is it for Linux only? Will it work with windows?